# Tree with strange looking, grey-brown 10cm seed capsules

Tags: identification

while hiking in Central Europe the other day, I encountered a small tree having really odd looking seeds. These are about 10 cm long and contain two seeds. The outside feels a little bit like a short fur. The picture shows the open seed capsule.

[image]

**Question: Any idea what kind of tree (or bush) that is and what it needs if I want to grow it?**

Thanks a lot!
Ronny

Comment: Is there any chance that you have a photo of the tree itself, and/or a closeup of its bark?

Comment: Wisteria or laburnum? But a photo of the entire plant would help.

Comment: Sorry, picked the seeds and only afterwards thought about posting this 

Comment: Siberian peashrub? Whatever it is, it looks like a legume.

Comment: Genista, Cytisus, etc. There are many Fabaceae shrubs (and trees) in Europe. If you took it from wild, it should be easy to reproduce without much work (if you have similar environment).

Comment: Looks very much like wisteria.

Comment: I guess your country is not strict about bringing foreign seeds in.  :-)

Comment: haha, in theory the EU is 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @Giacomo Catenazzi in the comments, if you want to try sprouting the seeds, just duplicate their natural environment. I assume that the tree/shrub is growing in a temperate climate, with a cold winter.

1. Pot the seeds maybe 2cm deep in a small pot with drainage holes, water well,remove excess water from the drainage saucer (if any) and then place the pot in a refrigerator or (better) an unheated shed or garage (protect from rodents if you do this).
2. Periodically, check for sprouting.

--If the seeds sprout, move the pot into your house and treat as a houseplant.

--If the plants don't sprout, remove the pot from the refrigerator or shed in, say, late February or early March and put under lights or in a window.

3. Water as needed.

I've had success doing this with *Aesculus*, *Cercis*, and *Acer* species.

Alternatively, plant the seeds outside, mark the location, protect from rodents with screening, and see what happens in the spring.